# Change home page to custom page in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

In DotnetNuke, home page of site can be set to pages created through Administrator portal only. Is there anyway to set custom page as home page.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I think you can make the homepage redirect to your custom page.
For example, go to the Home page > Page Settings > Advanced Settings > Other Settings and set Link Url to URL (A link to an external resource). Then you can put anything in there. You can also make it a permanent redirect.